# Linux redirect input via proc fd0, dev/pts

Tags: linux, shell, proc, pts

In Ubuntu 13.04 Using VMware, I have two terminals(PID 1000 - /dev/pts0, PID 2000 - /dev/pts2)
If I do this from terminal 2(/dev/pts2) ...

```
echo 'ls -al' > /proc/1000/fd/0
```

I can see that 'ls -al' prompts up in terminal 0(/dev/pts0)
however, this is just a visual result, not a real command input for terminal 0.

[image]

What I want is redirect the actual command input from terminal 2 to terminal 0 via /proc/pid(terminal 0's)/fd/0 and execute command from terminal 0.

Is this possible??, if it is, how can I do this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because a bash does two things when the keyboard event `<ENTER>` happens.

1. Printing a newline.
2. Executing the entered command, if the command is completed.

The logic, when a command is completed is not simple. It depends on conditional statements, backslashes etc.

Redirecting a '\n' character to the stdin will only execute the first step. I guess it is impossible by design, because a shell, that could be controlled by another shell is horrible for every security engineer.

On a multi-user linux, you would be able to write and execute commands on shells, that are running by different users (e.g. root). You are able to do nasty things (e.g. blame other users for doing forbidden things).

**If you still need a solution:**

You could write a script, that reads commands from a pipe and executes them under a different user, but beware: This isn't secure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a terminal and a shell. When you see a pts window, there are both a terminal-emulator (pts) and a shell (bash) running there. Bash is reading lines from the pts device and executes commands. Bash writes its stdout/stderr back into the pts device, and the programs started by bash do so too. But the pts itself is just a glorified serial terminal. It displays characters written into it, and you (bash) can read characters typed into it. Usually it also echoes (displays) the typed characters.

When you write into a pts device from another terminal, it displays the characters, but these characters cannot be read from the pts device. You (bash) can only read from the pts what a user types.

The confusing thing is that displaying characters written into the pts device (this is what you tried) and echoing the typed characters look exactly the same.